# What's worse, failing or be approved with a bad grade?

Tags: academic-life, grades

I am in a very bad situation and would like some advise and claryfy a doubt.

I had a very troubled semester and I will probably fail most of the classes. It was an exception, but I can't save this semester anymore, it's already over, but I have the option to do a special exam for some classes. In my university, the special exam is a test including all semester content, of a given subject, that I can do at the end the semester if I reached 40% during the semester, the end score is an aritimetical average of the special test and my score during the semester.

I'm not sure if I try approval in the special exam, even if I don't learn so much and my grade became low, or if I do the semester again learning it right, since the problems that I had in the last semester no longer exists. What would you advise in this case?

One question I have is this: to get a scholarship or enter a master's program at a university, which would be worse, failing or low grades on the academic record?

Comment: In your institution, what happens if you retake the exact same class? In some, your old grade is replaced completely.

Comment: Agree, I think this really depends on your institution's policies. Some schools allow you to retake only failed classes (not classes you passed but did poorly in) but the original grade won't affect your GPA if you retake and pass. Others have no such policy.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! You may want to check out our [help]; we're a little different from some other sites. In particular, we don't take "survey questions" like "how does X work at your school?" Also, we try not to change (or delete) the question after people have answered it, since this would invalidate their answers. Instead, you can just leave this post as it is and post new questions in a new post (but do check out our [help] first to see what kinds of questions we can help with). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Both are bad, but if you can list and document reasons for the bad semester you can recover. Passing will enable you to move forward more quickly, however, rather than repeating a semester, which might delay you a year.

A lot of students have had trouble due to COVID. Others due to personal and family issues. Exceptional things can be explained and none of us need to think we need to be perfect.

Which courses give you trouble might be a deciding issue. Some are more important than others for your progress and it might be necessary to do *something* to assure you have the required knowledge. You need to decide whether you can let some things go (low grades) or really need to get needed instruction (repeating).

You might also consider whether your institution will allow you to re-take courses that you have technically passed in order to get a better grade. Some places replace the older grade with the newer. That can change your analysis. If so, take the special exam and then decide how to proceed.